# What is the equivalent key in Google Spreadsheet to Excel's F2 for editing a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel

## In Excel

When you want to edit the highlighted cell, and you don't want to move back to the previous cell when pressing the <kbd><-</kbd> key, you press <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> ensures that when you're editing the cell, the cursor will move back to the previous character and not the previous cell.

## In Google Spreadsheets?

In Google Spreadsheets, the only way to achieve similar functionality to <kbd>F2</kbd> in Excel is by double-clicking the cell with the mouse.

Pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> on the selected cell in Google Spreadsheets re-instantiates the behavior where pressing the <kbd><-</kbd> key moves you to the previous cell.

## Question

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Google Spreadsheets that creates the same behavior
as the Excel <kbd>F2</kbd> key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [official list of keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181110), <kbd>F2</kbd> is the only key responsible for editing a cell. I've just tried it in 3 browsers (Chrome 16, Firefox 9, and IE 9) and it doesn't function the same way as it does in Excel.

Your solutions are **1)** pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> before entering any data, **2)** pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to remove the characters you've typed after the error, or **3)** using the mouse to navigate.

Comment: Pressing <kbd>F2</kdb> before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> seems to do the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This has been fixed in Google Spreadsheets. You may now use the <kbd>F2</kbd> key to begin editing without clicking in the cell.

Comment: Not on a mac it appears... F2 just turns up the brightness. Do you know if there is an equivalent for Mac?

Comment: @redOctober13 This is not an issue with Google Spreadsheets, but a "feature" of your Mac. You have to change the function keys to act as function keys. They don't do this by default. https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204436